# Conflict resolution unsolved due to html closing tag in index.html but source file and destination file are the same

Tags: html, angular, version-control, bitbucket, pull-request

I am attempting to make a pull request to merge my code with the master, but there is a conflict in the src/index.html file that says line 17 `</html>` is incorrect and should instead be line 17 `</html>`, which makes no sense to me because they are the same code, identical. I even copied the full text from the master and pasted it and it did not solve the conflict.

I copied the full text from the master and pasted it and it did not solve the conflict. I tried moving it to line 16 to no avail. I tried to fetch the master code from the remote server again to see if things had changed.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">


<head>

    <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-29834987-3"></script>

    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport" charset="utf-8" />

    <title>Shopping Cart</title>

    <base href="/" />

</head>


<body>

    <app-root> </app-root>

</body>


<<<<<<< destination:cc848bca09231a760af4f0930bb96a80da61cada
</html>
=======
</html>
>>>>>>> source:25a45ae34916ad4611294273dcd694d1e191edf7
```

Conflict: File modified in both source and destination
To be able to merge you will need to resolve the conflicts manually.

The expected result would be for it to pass, but it continues to hold up progress and I don't know what else to try.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just used source tree to merge and picked the option to use their version. I couldn't figure out what it thought the conflict was.